# Microsoft Installer Appears to be behind updated Code-base

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, msbuild, windows-installer

I am developing a C# .NET desktop app in a team and we use TFS to do versioning. We work on our individual machine and give the build(make Setup) from a machine where no one works.

It's happening that, every now and then a change we recently checked in does not appear in the setup file created after getting the latest version.
I am quite sure about getting latest version, because the last build I made had changes in only one of the file and i verified that this was updated properly.

Is there some issue as to why the setup file created always seems to be a bit behind. Is it using codes that last compiled successfully and not the latest. I can also assure you that there were no compile error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're running into a wonderful problem known as "Checking Binaries Into Source Control"!

You're best best is to always do a clean/build before each checkin. VS2008 has a nasty habit of not wanting to build from TFS if you end up with an older checkin. Doing a clean/rebuild all should do the trick.

Comment: I hope your words are worth taking :). It's really giving us pain.